# Show that the following is a solution to the pde

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Hi i was wondering if anyone could help me show that

$$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\tau}x}(e^{2\sqrt{\tau}(l-x)}-1)}{(a+t-\tau)(e^{2\sqrt{\tau}l}-1)}d\tau$$
is a solution to the heat equation problem given by $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}},0<x<l,t>0$$

subject to $u(0,t)=e^{-at},t>0$, $u(l,t)=0,t>0$, $u(x,0)=0,0<x<l$
Only from the use of Laplace transformations.

I will now show my working. I get stuck at the last step.

Solution: Taking the Laplace transform of the pde in the $t$-direction gives

$$\mathcal{L}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t})=\mathcal{L}(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}).$$

From this we get that $$0=\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}U(s,x)-SU(x,s).$$

Now note that this is a 2nd order ode, so the characteristic equation is $$m^{2}-s=0\implies m=\sqrt{s},$$

therefore $$U(x,s)=a(s)e^{\sqrt{s}x}+b(s)e^{-\sqrt{s}x}.$$

Now taking the Laplace transform of the first condition gives $$\mathcal{L}(u(0,t))=\mathcal{L}(e^{-at})=\frac{1}{a+s}.$$

Also, the Laplace transforms of the other conditions give:
$$ \mathcal{L}(u(l,t))=\mathcal{L}(0)\Rightarrow U(l,s)=0, $$
and $$\mathcal{L}(u(x,0))=\mathcal{L}(0) \Rightarrow U(x,0)=0. $$
Applying these conditions to the characteristic equation is where I stopped as I'm confused where to go next.

Comment: Your equation is a $\displaystyle t$-$\displaystyle \color{red}{\texttt{first}}\ \texttt{order}$ equation and you have $\displaystyle \color{red}{\texttt{two}}$ $\displaystyle t$-boundary conditions.

Comment: I think you may have misread the question

Comment: Indeed, I read it very carefully. Your boundary conditions are not consistent at all. For instance, $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0^{+}}\mathrm{u}\left(0,t\right) = 1 \not= \,\mathrm{u}\left(0,0\right) = 0$.

Comment: but don't we have that $u(0,t)=e^{-at},t>0$?

Comment: This was a past exam question

Comment: Thanks. It's a nice question.

Comment: Is it impossible to solve it then since the conditions are inconsistent?

Comment: The integral does not seem to satisfy $u(0,t)=e^{-at}$. Instead, ît yields $$u(0,t)=\int_0^t\frac{d\tau}{a+t-\tau}=-\ln(a)+\ln(a+t)=\ln\left(1+\frac{t}{a}\right).$$